# Sending buffer instead of file with SimpleHTTPServer

Tags: python, simplehttpserver

Is it possible to send binary data buffer via SimpleHTTPServer instead of a file? I'm generating some data that I rather not write to disk. If not is there any minimal python webserver that can do that? I just need to send the buffer via GET request.

Comment: This is off-topic on stackoverflow.com, rather ask the question on superuser.com

Comment: Unless OP's talking about the Python 2 module, in that case this is very on topic

Comment: @yorodm: yes, maybe you're right, but the question is anyway very low quality, without own research effort and not really clear what the intention is.